# Jquery Remove Class with Click

Tags: jquery

I have been working on this for a bit now and just can't seem to get it to work. Where my problem is is that the css class is not being removed.

```
jQuery$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about').click(function(){
        $('#about').addClass('bookOpen').before('<a href="#" class="closeButton">Close</a>');
    });

    $('.closeButton').click(function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass('bookOpen');         
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried .live()?

Try calling each click this way:

$('#about').live("click",function() {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `.click` since you are dynamically adding DOM elements.

```
$('.closeButton').live('click', function() {
    $(this).next().removeClass('bookOpen'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#about').click(function() {
        $('#about').addClass('bookOpen').before(
            '<a href="#" class="closeButton">Close</a>');
    });
    $('.closeButton').live('click', function() {
        $(this).next().removeClass('bookOpen');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
jQuery$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about').click(function(){
        $('#about').addClass('bookOpen').before('<a href="#" class="closeButton">Close</a>');
    });

    $('.closeButton').live('click', function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass('bookOpen');         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically add something to the DOM, you need to re-add any jquery triggers to the new piece of DOM.